# Parse string into JSONArray in velocity template

Tags: json, velocity

I am looking for a way to parse a string into json array, so that I can iterate the same and access the objects inside it. I have been looking around for some time but no help.

I found one way which is

```
#set ($myjson = $json.fetch('http://www.url.org/feeds/json-packages.dot'))
```

but I want to parse one local string variable into json array. How can we do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a library like [this](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java), and put in your velocity context a "JSONUtils" object. This object would expose a method "jsonArrayFromString", whose implementation would be as simple as

```
public JSONArray jsonArrayFromString(String jsonString) {
    try {
        return new JSONArray(jsonString);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Here is the documentation of the [JSONArray](http://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/index.html) class. Then you can use this object in your template like this:

```
#set ($myjson = $JSONUtils.jsonArrayFromString($myString))
#set ($length = $myjson.length())
#foreach( $i in [0..$length-1] )
  ## Use one of the getter methods for the object in this index.
#end
```

Of course you could also put a similar method that creates a JSONObject from a string.